# ASP.NET Grid View vs. List View

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview, gridview

What are the advantages of using listview over gridview?  I need pagination, editing rows, inserting rows, and deleting rows in my view.  Which control is best for that?  It seems like GridView does not support data pager.  What would I sacrifice if I migrated my gridviews to listviews?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

GridView supports:

- sorting by click
- paging
- editing
- selection
- template-based layout (rendered within `<table>`)

ListView supports:

- List item
- paging (need to use DataPager)
- editing
- selection
- sorting by click (need to create an event handler manually)
- template-based layout (rendered as you want it + provides more templates, e.g. - GroupTemplate)

**The reason to use ListView would be if you need some special layout**, for example, to create a table that places more than one item in the same row, or to break free from table-based rendering altogether) - which is not possible with GridView.

**Using GridView** on the other hand **is easier and faster**, so unless you need special layout to display your data, use GridView.

Answer (score 11):

[This article is particularly useful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667439/Comparing-ListView-with-GridView-DataList-and-Repe) for a comparison.

For me it is the raw flexibility of the HTML you can render. In a project I was developing I was using a GridView but replaced with the ListView as I wanted very specific paging requirements that couldn't be provided by the GridView. I could have used a 3rd party gridview to provide the paging requirements, but I wanted to minimise the reliance of 3rd party code.

The ListView alone in my opinion is a good reason for moving from ASP.NET 2.0 to 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Its realy depend/requirement on the scenario which control to be use
Listview is completely template driven and support of inserting records, you can use a regular html table and style it with CSS for presenting data, you have much control over design layout.

On the other hand GridView, you can insert records, but that can involve using
 the footer and your objectdatasource_inserting event. You need to find and capture the entered data in the gridview footer then directly add into input parameters of your objectdatasource.

Answer (score 2):

ListView gives you more control over resulting HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is the best option. You are able to do all of the things you mentioned much easier than anyother control. A listview is derived from a ListBox

The ListView control supports the following features:

- support for binding to data source
  controls such as SqlDataSource,
  LinqDataSource, and ObjectDataSource.

  Customizable appearance through
  user-defined templates and styles.

  Built-in sorting capabilities.

  Built-in update and delete
  capabilities.

  Built-in insert capabilities.

  Support for paging capabilities by
  using a DataPager control.

  Built-in item selection capabilities.

  Programmatic access to the ListView
  object model to dynamically set
  properties, handle events, and so on.

  Multiple key fields.

  ---

  GridView Displays the values of a data source in a table where each column represents a field and each row represents a record. The GridView control enables you to select, sort, and edit these items.

The GridView control is used to display the values of a data source in a table. Each column represents a field, while each row represents a record. The GridView control supports the following features:

- Binding to data source controls, such
  as SqlDataSource.

  Built-in sort capabilities.

  Built-in update and delete
  capabilities.

  Built-in paging capabilities.

  Built-in row selection capabilities.

  Programmatic access to the GridView
  object model to dynamically set
  properties, handle events, and so on.

  Multiple key fields.

  Multiple data fields for the
  hyperlink columns.

  Customizable appearance through
  themes and styles.

  To learn about the other data-bound
  controls that are available in
  ASP.NET, see ASP.NET Data-Bound Web
  Server Controls Overview.