# Usage the Listview over the gridview

Tags: asp.net

i am very much familier with gridview. listview and gridview both is used to generate tabular output with data. so please discuss what are the benefits that one should use the listview instead of gridview. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Comparing ListView with
   GridView,DataList and Repeater](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx)
2. [Grid View vs List View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/891918/102112)
3. [Repeater, ListView, DataList, DataGrid, GridView … Which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose)
4. [Gridview Vs ListView](http://forums.asp.net/p/1274913/2420770.aspx)