# Insert in gridView as new Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i'm new in ASP.NET i'm trying make a library in WebForms, and i have a problem with GridView. When i have a book in DropDownList and choose some book and push button, where i have set some action, so i call method, which INSERT data INTO my database. And now if i want to show all books in gridView, it is ok, but i don't know how i Add a new Column, where i want to in every row Some Link, which is simmilar, like button action and call it my Methods for Insert Data into databse like in previous case, and i need from every row get Id_book as primary key again. Is is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider working with ListView and not GridView.
The difference is that you can design your layout the way you want.
If you would like to read more about it - you can here:

[First Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667439/Comparing-ListView-with-GridView-DataList-and-Repe)

[Second Link - from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891918/grid-view-vs-list-view)